# multiple number change, at a rate? with a ratio? fold?

Tags: word-choice

> A (a=1, b=2, c=3)
>   then,
>   B (a=1.5, b=3, c=4.5)
>   C (a=3, b=6, c=9)
>   D (a=0.5, b=1, c=1.5)

As above, based on the amounts of the elements in group A, the elements of B, C, and D were changed (increased or decreased) by multiplying A by 1.5, 3, and 0.5, respectively.

How can I express these changes to B, C and D collectively?

So far I have these options:

> 1. The amount of each element in each group of B,C and D was increased or decreased at a specific rate as compared to A
> 2. The amount of each element in each group of B,C and D was changed with a specific fold increase or decrease as compared to A
> 3. The amount of each element in each group of B,C and D was changed by a specific ratio in relation to A

Or any better answers?

Comment: None of these. For starters, "the amount" makes no sense at all. It should be "the values". Also, "B,C" is not English. English would be "B, C".

Comment: a : b : c was held constant in each ordered triple.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> Groups B, C and D are *constant multiples* of Group A

Which would imply that each element in the set has been multiplied by the same number.

If your groups are vectors (or matrices) then you should rather use the term [*scalar multiple*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Scalar_multiplication)

And if a, b and c form a coordinate system then B would be a *scaling* of A.

Answer (score 0):

Say that each of a,b, and c were multiplied by a certain **factor** in each instance, to yield the next row (B, C, D).